# Append image before the a href depending on its URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple list like

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to append the **different** images to the list items before the `<a></a>` tags there depending on the URL so I could have something like that:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="img-1.png"> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><img src="img-2.png"> <a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><img src="img-3.png"> <a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Unfortunately I'm not expert in javascript so would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can I ask you why do you want to do that in JS? Of course it is possible in JS, but why?

Comment: @RoboRobok thank you for your question. The reason why I ask is because this list generates automatically with php and I don't have a possibility to change its (list item) content manually

Comment: How about CSS background? You can define CSS rules via attribute values too.

Comment: It's fine also, but I can't get how to add them depending on the URLs

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it in CSS like this:

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    background-size: 32px auto; /* if the image is bigger */
}

a[href='index.html'] {
    background-image: url('img-1.png');
}

a[href='about.html'] {
    background-image: url('img-2.png');
}

a[href='contact.html'] {
    background-image: url('img-3.png');
}
```